# How to listen to 0.0.0.0:8080 with ListenTCP

Tags: go, tcp

How can I listen on TCP port `8080` with `net.ListenTCP` ?

With `net.Conn` I simply do this:

```golang
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
```

Whats the simplest solution for `ListenTCP`?

Comment: You usually don't need the extra step to `ResolveTCPAddr`, as your `net.Listen` call returns a `*TCPListener` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [net.ListenTCP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenTCP), you must construct a [net.TCPAddr](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPAddr) struct. The simplest way is to [resolve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ResolveTCPAddr) one from the same string you pass to `Dial` or `Listen`:

```
addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":8000")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ln, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addr)
```

Per the comments on net.ResolveTCPAddr, valid combinations of "network" and "address" can be found in the [net.Dial](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial) documentation.